# kicking / logging out remote windows users?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, kill

I'd like to have something akin to a unix "who" and an option to kick out RDP sessions that are not supposed to be there (i.e. using up the limited number of connections). This is for a win2003 server Standard.

Additional info: this is a devel environment, people all use RDP as Administrator (I know, I know), so kicking out should be by session number or at least by remote IP/machine name, not per user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Refer this [post](http://www.techtalkz.com/blog/tips-n-tricks/how-to-view-disconnect-remote-desktop-sessions-from-commandline.html) on kicking the users.

The summary of the commands is as follows:

*Use [**qwinsta**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/qwinsta) to get a list of the Remote Sessions in the command window (Get the session Id of user to kick out):*

```
qwinsta /server:SERVERIP
```

*Use [**rwinsta**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rwinsta) to disconnect the remote session:*

```
rwinsta /server:SERVERIP SESSIONID
```

Also you may want to change the default timeout for idle RDP connections.[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726057(WS.10).aspx) or [here](http://www.syncrony.com/Syncrony-Web-Design-BLOG/entryid/7/Setting-RDP-Session-Timeout-Policy-in-Windows-Server-2003.aspx).

Comment: yup, I just found this post listing also quser and rwinsta: http://anandpv.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AFCCA5892B178862!804.entry

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should also be able to do this by pulling up Task Manager and going to Users and selecting users to Logoff or Disconnect. Disconnect will close their RDP session, but they can log back in to it. Logoff will... well, log off their current session.

Comment: That would mean you were on the machine in question. What if you want to connect to a machine that is full already :)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 or other client OS from Microsoft, some of the MSTSC options will not work. As a last resort you may want to try restarting the machine (if that is an option)

`shutdown /m mydevbox.myorg.com /r /f /t 0`

Answer (score 0):

`mstsc /console` or `mstsc /admin` should let you always log on, but it will kick off anyone else who's logged in using the same technique.